# do all functions have a "function prologue" that decrements the stack pointer for locals?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, att

I have a few basic questions regarding assembly.

when writing a function in assembly, do all functions have a "function prologue"? I'm seeing some functions written online and they don't have it which is confusing me. I would think you always need it for the new base pointer and local variables by decrementing stack?

Also does every push instruction require a subtract instruction for the stackpointer because we always want the stack pointer to be at the top of the stack and if not why? so if

```
 push %eax
 sub $4, %esp
```

My last question is, are there any resources out there to explain assembly in laymans terms?

Comment: The prologue is not strictly necessary, but it does help the debugger if no unwind or debug information is provided.  The `push` instruction implicitly subtracts `4` from the stack pointer, that's the whole point of having it.  Please refer to an assembly tutorial for details.

Comment: why would you ever sub from the stack pointer if push does it for you?

Comment: Assembly language per se doesn't really care what you do. However, the code you interoperate with may care.

Comment: still a little confused. Pop and push decrements/adds to stack pointer like you said, can you provide an example where sub from stack pointer is needed?

Comment: You can use `sub` to quickly allocate a chunk of stack. Say, you need 128 bytes for a buffer, you can do `sub $128, %esp`. Imagine having to do 32 `push`es of garbage instead.

Comment: @cloudiebro You decrease the stack pointer when you want to make space on the stack but don't care what content that memory has.  A very common use case.

Comment: What do you mean by explain assembly in laymans terms?  The processor vendor docs usually do a good job.  It really doesnt get much simpler than assembly, small, digestable (understandable) building blocks.  Like looking at a house or building and saying can you explain what the bricks are doing?  Add, sub, xor, or, flavors of jumps or branches, some way to call and return from a function.  There you go the building blocks of a computer program, same building blocks used in higher level languages.   What part of it do you not understand?

Comment: As far as what the stack pointer points to entering a "function call" is specific to that compilers calling convention, for which there can be more than one/many for each instruction set, but often are not more than  a few.  In general though each entry into a function assumes the stack pointer is a the tip of the stack (either next free spot or last used spot depending on the architecture) and the memory beyond that is fair game for that function to use/modify.  So before calling some other function you need to move the stack pointer to cover your local allocation.

Comment: If you are not calling a function then depending on the architecture you can optimize that modification out, but usually you want/need the stack pointer at the tip anyway in case there is an interrupt.  Again depends on the architecture and how many stacks there are, etc.  Some architectures stack pointer relative accesses are only in one direction (sp + some offset for example) allowing for twice the reach, but requires the sp to be on the far side of all the local information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its fairly trivial to make your own example, just need something on the stack in the function (that doesnt optimize away).

```
unsigned int more_fun ( unsigned int );
void fun_too ( unsigned int *);
void fun ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    unsigned int ray[64];
    for(ra=0;ra<64;ra++) ray[ra]=more_fun(ra);
    fun_too(ray);
}



0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   53                      push   %rbx
   1:   31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
   3:   48 81 ec 10 01 00 00    sub    $0x110,%rsp
   a:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
  11:   00 00 
  13:   48 89 84 24 08 01 00    mov    %rax,0x108(%rsp)
  1a:   00 
  1b:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  1d:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
  20:   89 df                   mov    %ebx,%edi
  22:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  27 <fun+0x27>
  27:   89 04 9c                mov    %eax,(%rsp,%rbx,4)
  2a:   48 83 c3 01             add    $0x1,%rbx
  2e:   48 83 fb 40             cmp    $0x40,%rbx
  32:   75 ec                   jne    20 <fun+0x20>
  34:   48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
  37:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  3c <fun+0x3c>
  3c:   48 8b 84 24 08 01 00    mov    0x108(%rsp),%rax
  43:   00 
  44:   64 48 33 04 25 28 00    xor    %fs:0x28,%rax
  4b:   00 00 
  4d:   75 09                   jne    58 <fun+0x58>
  4f:   48 81 c4 10 01 00 00    add    $0x110,%rsp
  56:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  57:   c3                      retq
```

(it is not linked so the immediate in the call's are zeros so the linker can fill them in)

Instead of subtracting or adding a constant to rsp, you could instead put a long list of pushes and pops as Jester pointed out in the comments.  This is just a waste of code space and execution time, the add and subtract make more sense.

Now one could argue that you could implement this code such that each time through the loop you push the result of more_fun();  Growing the stack only as needed for the function, and using pushes as you desire rather than subtracting from rsp. But on the return you would want to add to rsp in one instruction rather than waste time and space on individual pops or a loop of pops.  This solution is harder to debug as a compiler author, and harder to understand as a user/reader of the compiler output.  (and if you wanted to maintain say a 64 bit alignment on the stack and say an unsigned int here is 32 bits as shown, then you would be burning a handful more instructions just to sort that out)